# Can a Form be prevented from closing until a criteria is met?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have setup a time tracking .exe file which basically saves the user input data to a .csv file. I already have a code setup for a criteria that the user cannot save a file unless ' at least 8 hours' have been met.

However, I also want to make the .exe file stay open (kind of like forced open) unless the user manages to save the file. The user should not be allowed to close the program unless the '8 hours ' criteria is met. Any help would be appreciated. 
This is a section of my code from where the criteria is being determine:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox28.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox29.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox36.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox40.Text) < 8)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Total hours should be at least 8");
        }
        else
        {
            StreamWriter myOutputStream = new StreamWriter("C:\\demo\\test.csv",true);
            myOutputStream.WriteLine((dateTimePicker1.Text) + "," + (textBox47.Text) + "," + (textBox28.Text) + "," + (textBox29.Text) + "," + (textBox2.Text) + "," + (textBox3.Text) + "," + (textBox4.Text) + "," + (textBox6.Text) + "," + (textBox5.Text) + "," + (textBox7.Text) + "," + (textBox36.Text) + "," + (textBox40.Text));  
            myOutputStream.Close();


        }
    }
```

Comment: This is technically not possible. The user can always stop the process via the Task Manager regardless of what you do in the application code.

Comment: I am well aware of that. But I meant more like the user shouldnt be able to just press 'X' without a criteria being met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [`Closing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the `Form` and check if you want to cancel the closing process:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool closeCriteriaMet;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        // subscribe event
        Closing += OnFormClosing;
    }

    // "Closing" event handler
    private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = !closeCriteriaMet; // tell the Form not to close 
    }
}
```

Or (as [LarsTech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180911/can-a-form-be-prevented-from-closing-until-a-criteria-is-met/46180994#comment79324633_46180994) suggested) simply override the `OnFormClosing` method

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    // "Closing" event handler
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        e.Cancel |= !closeCriteriaMet; // combine the cancel flag 
    }
}
```

But note that this only prevents the user from closing the form via UI. The process can still be killed via Task manager or other tools.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just override the OnFormClosing method?  Forms don't need to listen to their own events.

Comment: @LarsTech you're right, strange thing that I never did it that way, probably because back then I started with the designer which always added handlers instead of overriding...

Comment: @LarsTech, this is perfectly valid for a class to listen to own events. You don't even need to bother with unsubscribing. The overriding approach for the most winforms classes has a pitfall however - once you've forgotten to call the base implementation, you'll never receive the corresponding events anymore. This may be hard to debug then.

Comment: @dymanoid I didn't say it was invalid, and I didn't say anything about unsubscribing.  It's just not a needed step.  If the user comments out or removes the base call, then that's the user's fault.  I rarely see that happen.

Comment: @leo you could set `closeCriteriaMet = true;` in your `else` block.

Comment: @LarsTech I really appreciate the comment you have posted. But, I am kind of a newbie to all this and I am a little confused as to how I can integrate it to my code. I have made an edit on this post showing the section of my program which is determining the criteria. How do I go about this?

Comment: @RenéVogt When I try it, it says 'closeCriteriaMet' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @leo As you can see in my first example, **I** declared that `closeCriteriaMet` field. Just do so in your class, too.